# When decoding a Codable struct from JSON, how do you initialize a property not present in the JSON?

Tags: swift, codable

Say that in [this example here](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/making-reminders-identifiable), this struct

```
struct Reminder: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var dueDate: Date
    var notes: String? = nil
    var isComplete: Bool = false
}
```

is instead decoded from JSON array values (rather than constructed like in the linked example). If each JSON value were to be missing an "id", how would `id` then be initialized? When trying this myself I got an error `keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))`.

Comment: You add your own CodingKey enum with all properties except the id. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: you can also do this: `let id: String = UUID().uuidString`, note the `let`. The compiler will give you a very useful message: `Immutable property will not be decoded ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use coding keys, like this:

```
struct Reminder: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var dueDate: Date
    var notes: String? = nil
    var isComplete: Bool = false
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case dueDate
        case notes
        case isComplete
    }
}
```

That way, the only properties that will be encoded/decoded are the ones that have a corresponding coding key.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer is nice.

To have full control, you need to override the default decoding.

```swift
struct Reminder: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var dueDate: Date
    var notes: String? = nil
    var isComplete: Bool = false
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    
        id = (try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)) ?? UUID()
        title = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: . title)
        dueDate = try values.decode(Date.self, forKey: . dueDate)
        notes = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .notes)
        isComplete = try values.decode(Bool.self, forKey: . isComplete)
    }
}
```

I go a little bit beyond the question, but why is `id` not set in the JSON?

- If `id` is a database key, then it must be present in the json.
- On the other side, if `id` is a unique identifier to identify items in UI, then it is much safer and clean to use a dedicated object that describes the object representation.

```swift
struct ReminderItem: Identifiable {
   let id = UUID()
   let reminder: Reminder
}
```

By the way, it works the same way for encoding.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered this problem in my own framework `ColorKit`
I downloaded a 450000 line JSON database from GitHub and found out it has no `id`  while my `SingleColor` model is `Identifiable`
AHHHHH
So I went to to add `id` to them one by one for a couple of days and realized I could actually create a `struct` that's without the `id` called the `SingleColorInit` and load the JSON into this model and then casting all of my data into my `SingleColor` model.
Code:

```
public struct SingleColorInit: Codable, Hashable{
    public var name: String
    public var hex: String
    public var rgb: RGBList
    public var hsl: HSLList
    public var luminance: Double
}
public struct SingleColor: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable{
    public var id: UUID = UUID()
    public var name: String
    public var hex: String
    public var rgb: RGBList
    public var hsl: HSLList
    public var luminance: Double
}

let coloKey: [InitColor] = load("database.json")
public func database() -> [SingleColor] {
    var returnData: [SingleColor] = []
    for datum in colorKey {
        returnData.append(SingleColor(name: datum.name, hex: datum.hex, rgb: datum.rgb, hsl: datum.hsl, luminance: datum.luminance))
    }
    returnData.remove(at: 0)
    return returnData
}
```

so when I create a new instance of the object the UUID will be generated.
In your case you can do this:

```
struct InitReminder {
    var title: String
    var dueDate: Date
    var notes: String? = nil
    var isComplete: Bool = false
}

struct Reminder: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var dueDate: Date
    var notes: String? = nil
    var isComplete: Bool = false
}

// load your data (I use the load method in Apple's SwiftUI tutorial)

let reminders: [Reminder] = load("youdatabase.json")

func database() -> [Reminder] {
    var returnData: [Reminder] = []
    for datum in reminders{
        returnData.append(Reminder(title: datum.title, dueDate: datum.dueDate, notes: datum.notes, isComplete: datum.isComplete))
    }
    return returnData
}
```

And then I realized...
As long as my structure is hashable (which can be implemented in all cases of nominal structures)
In SwiftUI's(if you use it) `List` or `ForEach`, it does not need it to be `Identifiable`; use each item's `self` as the `id`. Just do this:

```
List(yourData, id: \.self) { item in
   ...
}
ForEach(yourData, id: \.self) { item in
   ...
}
```

This is problem has annoyed me long time really I'm really happy to share this solution to someone who need it
It's really annoying
hope it'll help